# Google Spreadsheets Copy Value and Formats Script Issues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have tried to search a lot and found various suggestion but none of them are working correctly for me.

I have 4 separate google spreadsheets (owned by myself) that various members in our team update.  I want to build a combined spreadsheet that automatically updates the values they change (Values and Color of the cell as we color code various items).

I have tried `Importrange` (works but does not bring formatting), as well as also trying `copyValuesandFormatting` and `copyFormatting`.  The issue I come up with is with `CopyValuesandFormatting` is that it will only fill out the first tab, and the next part of the script will not work.  Does anybody know what my issue may be?  The part of the script that I have been working on is below (only got through trying to get 2 of the sheets to combine and that would not work).

```
function copyValuesandFormatting() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("OtherSheetURL1");
     var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Jayson");
     var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("CombinedSheetURL");  
     var targetSheet = ss2.getSheetByName("Jayson");
     var fromRange = ss.getRange("A1:Z50");
     var toRange = ss2.getRange("A1:Z50");
     var values = fromRange.getValues();
     var fontColors = fromRange.getFontColors();
     var backgrounds = fromRange.getBackgrounds();
     var fonts = fromRange.getFontFamilies();
     var fontWeights = fromRange.getFontWeights();
     var fontStyles = fromRange.getFontStyles();

    toRange.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
    toRange.setFontColors(fontColors);
    toRange.setValues(values);
    toRange.setFontFamilies(fonts);
    toRange.setFontWeights(fontWeights);
    toRange.setFontStyles(fontStyles);

} 

function copyValuesandFormatting() {
    var ss3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("OtherSheetURL2");
    var sourceSheet = ss3.getSheetByName("Robin");
    var ss4 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("CombinedSheetURL");
    var targetSheet = ss4.getSheetByName("Robin");

    var fromRange = ss3.getRange("A1:Z50");
    var toRange = ss4.getRange("A1:Z50");
    var values = fromRange.getValues();
    var fontColors = fromRange.getFontColors();
    var backgrounds = fromRange.getBackgrounds();
    var fonts = fromRange.getFontFamilies();
    var fontWeights = fromRange.getFontWeights();
    var fontStyles = fromRange.getFontStyles();

    toRange.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
    toRange.setFontColors(fontColors);
    toRange.setValues(values);
    toRange.setFontFamilies(fonts);
    toRange.setFontWeights(fontWeights);
    toRange.setFontStyles(fontStyles);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was able to use CopyTo in each one of the original sheets to make it work this morning.

```
function copyTo( {
  //gets and formats data ranges, to and from sheets.
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
   var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("DestinationURL");
   var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Jayson");
   var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Jayson");
   var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A1:Z100");
   var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A1:Z100");
   //gets then writes values defined in setup
   var values = source_range.getValues(); 
   var values = source_range.getValues();
   var fontColors = source_range.getFontColors();
   var backgrounds = source_range.getBackgrounds();
   var fonts = source_range.getFontFamilies();
   var fontWeights = source_range.getFontWeights();
   var fontStyles = source_range.getFontStyles();
   target_range.setValues(values);
   target_range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
   target_range.setFontColors(fontColors);
   target_range.setValues(values);
   target_range.setFontFamilies(fonts);
   target_range.setFontWeights(fontWeights);
   target_range.setFontStyles(fontStyles);
   //for checking last row with data in cell and formatting range
   var lastRow = source_sheet.getLastRow();
```